# DispatchQueue and [weak self] workItems. Is [weak self] necessary?

Tags: swift

I've got a custom class that uses a DispatchQueue.

```
class MyCustomClass {

    func fetch(fromURL url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in 
            // workItem stuff where self? is called
        }
    }

}
```

Is the [weak self] necessary? The workItem closure references the instance of MyCustomClass, so I see that strong reference, but does the instance of MyCustomClass keep a reference to the enclosed workItem block that's passed to async()? It seems like it doesn't, so is [weak self] unnecessary in this case?

Answer (score 5):

> but does the instance of MyCustomClass keep a reference to the enclosed workItem block that's passed to async()?

Not from this  example, no.

However, if the instance of `MyCustomClass` has a `DispatchQueue` that was used instead of the global queue, then that would strongly reference the work time until it's completed.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding your answer, but are you saying that if I use `DispatchQueue.main.async` I should use `[weak self]`?

Comment: @RIP.Ben.Franklin No, if you make your *own* dispatch queue, and store a reference to it in an instance of a `MyCustomClass`, *then* you'll have a strong reference cycle.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not needed the singleton `DispatchQueue.global()`

```
DispatchQueue.global().async
```

doesn't hold a strong reference to  `self` , GCD doesn't cause retain cycles

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why doesn't GCD cause retain cycles?

Comment: because it doesn't hold a strong reference to self